# How to execute powershell script from python with space in the path and parameters

Tags: python, powershell, subprocess

Path example: `C:\Users\user\Some Space\dev\sensor\`

```
def readSensorList():
    with open('sensor.json') as json_data:
        data = json.load(json_data)
    json_data.close()

return data
def executeSensor():
    sensorList = list()
    sensorListRaw = readSensorList()
    for sensor in sensorListRaw['sensors']:
        x = [subprocess.Popen(['powershell.exe','-ExecutionPolicy', 'Unrestricted', sensorListRaw["path"] + sensor["filename"], "-name", sensor["name"]], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE), sensor["name"]]
        sensorList.append(x)
    return sensorList
```

Json containing the path:

```
{
                "path": "C:\\Users\\\\sensor\\",
                "sensors": 
                    [{
                        "name": "partition",
                        "filename": "partition.ps1"
                    }]
            }
```

In my test environnement there were no space in the path, but now, in the production, I have some space in the path, and I'm clueless about how to execute powershell script from python with space and parameters

I tried to quote the path, without any success.

Edit: I'm sure the problem come from the powershell.exe command and not from python, because:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy 'Unrestricted C:\Users\some space\Desktop\PythonSensor\sensor\sensor.ps1'
```

Don't work in the CMD.

Comment: "I have some space in the path" What do you mean by that?

Comment: Could you print from the Python script the exact string that contains the space?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally found, you have to put ' between space like this:

```
powershell -command "C:\Users\me\Desktop\test\ps' 'test.ps1"
```

In python:

```
subprocess.Popen(['powershell','-ExecutionPolicy', 'Unrestricted', '-command', path]
```

with path as:

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop\some' 'space\sensor\
```

without " as Serge Ballesta explain.

Comment: many thanks for adding '  ' .... very interesting....

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not only with Python but also with Windows. Internally Unix-like system use an `execve` system call that takes as parameters the (path to) executable file and the arguments that will be passed to the command.

In Windows the system API has the function `CreateProcess` that takes as arguments the path to the executable file and the whole command line as a single string. It is then up to the child process to parse the command line to find its parameters

Python does its best to follow Windows internal usages to build a command line that will be parsed as expected, but it fails as soon as one parameter contains double quotes (`"`).

For example, if `foo.bat` is a batch script taking 3 parameters, this will be correct:

```
 proc = subprocess.Popen(('foo.bat', 'a', 'b c', 'd'),
    stdout= subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

foo will receive 3 parameters, `a`, `b c` and `d`.

But if you use:

```
 proc = subprocess.Popen(('foo.bat', '"a"', '"b c"', '"d"'),
    stdout= subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

foo will receive 4 parameters: `"a"`, `"b`, `c"` and `"d"`.

TL/DR: you must ensure that the string that contains a parameter that contains a space is **not** enclosed in `"`

Comment: I don't think the problem come from python, because if I print the command and do it in CMD in don't work...

I think the problem come from my Powershell syntax, but I can't find any solution after hours of test...

Answer (score 2):

Although process parameters/arguments are indeed handled somewhat inconsistent on Windows, this is not the problem in this case. Pythons `submodule.Popen` handles this correctly (based on [these rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/17w5ykft.aspx)). ([Serge Ballesta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3545273/serge-ballesta)s example of calling `.bat` files does not really fit, because `.bat` files are executed by `cmd.exe` and `cmd.exe` is almost the only application these days that doesn't follow [these rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/17w5ykft.aspx).)

The problem in this case, is the usage of `-Command`:

When PowerShell is called with the `-Command` parameter, all following arguments are joined to a single command (like `$args -join " "`). This command is then executed.

`-Command` is the default parameter: If a Parameter does not start with `-` or `/`, powershell behaves, as if `-Command` were present before.

This:

```
subprocess.Popen(['powershell.exe', r'C:\Users\user\Some Space\dev\sensor\partition.ps1', "-name", "partition"])
```

is therefore equivalent to this command in an interactive powershell session:

```
C:\Users\user\Some Space\dev\sensor\partition.ps1 -name partition
```

If you surround each space with quotes (as described in your own answer), the resulting powershell command is:

```
C:\Users\user\Some' 'Space\dev\sensor\partition.ps1 -name partition
```

This is allowed and works - but if your path contains other special characters like `$` or `` ` `` it will break again. It will also break if the 
script argument contains spaces or other special characters.

**tl;dr**:

To correctly call a powershell script from outside of powershell, use `-File` parameter:

```
subprocess.Popen(['powershell.exe','-ExecutionPolicy', 'Unrestricted', '-File', sensorListRaw["path"] + sensor["filename"], "-name:", sensor["name"]])
```

The parameter after `-File` is the script name (without any additional strange escaping), all following parameters are arguments to the script.

Notice the `:` appended to the parameter name (`-name:` instead of `-name`) - in most cases it will also work without the `:`, but if the corresponding value starts with a dash, it will fail without `:`.